# PHP while loop isn't working

Tags: php, database, loops, while-loop

I'm new to PHP and trying to produce numbers like this in a loop which is already being used in fetching the data from database table.

```
$i= 1;
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
/////////////////other codes
<img src="$i.jpg">
$i++;}
```

I want to stop the loop as long there are rows in the table.
Error:
It produces two, three images according to the number of rows but all images have source 1.jpg

Comment: The code you have provided does not contain the error you describe. Perhaps including more of the code may allow someone to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this isn't an answer to your problem, but it's the only answer possible at the moment:

This works for me:

```
<?php

$rows = [
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item'
];

function fetch() {
    global $rows;

    return count($rows) > 0 ? array_splice($rows,0,1)[0] : null;
    //Should match return behavior of fetch assoc according to: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
}

/**///Remove a star to toggle methods

$i = 1;
while($row = fetch()) {
    echo "$i<br>";
    $i++;
}

/*/

//Alternative method:

for ($i = 1; $row = fetch(); $i++)
    echo "Alt: $i<br>";

//*/
```

That outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
```

So the issue isn't with the code you shared.

Comment: can't put variable in while loop and you described in alternative method (last)?

Comment: @JahanzaibAsgher It's not a while loop, it's a for loop.  That code executes fine, I tested it.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @JahanzaibAsgher No worries.  Your code behaves as expected now?